# How to report step failure if a test does not pass

Tags: python, pytest, github-actions

In a GitHub Actions workflow, I run pytest:

```yaml
- name: running pytest
  run: poetry run pytest
```

When this is run on the server, one of the tests does not pass:

```
Run poetry run pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.16, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/runner/work/Package/Package
plugins: cov-4.0.0
collected 271 items

tests/test_base.py ....x......................................... [ 16%]
[...]
tests/test_utils.py ......                                        [100%]

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:121
  /home/runner/work/package/Package/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:121: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API
    warnings.warn("pkg_resources is deprecated as an API", DeprecationWarning)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
============ 270 passed, 1 xfailed, 1 warning in 182.06s (0:03:02) =============
```

yet the workflow step is set as success. How to have the step reporting error if one test or more does not pass?

Comment: Pytest should exit non-zero if any tests fail (see https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/exit-codes.html) and I wouldn't expect poetry to override that. What happens when you run locally with a failing test, what's the exit code of `poetry run pytest`?

Comment: It didn't fail, it xfailed (ie. it was marked as expected to fail) and thus doesn't cause pytest to error.

Comment: @thebjorn I did not know the concept of xfail, but indeed all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

One should just be aware of the difference between "fail" and "xfail".

from https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/skipping.html :

`An xfail means that you expect a test to fail for some reason. A common example is a test for a feature not yet implemented, or a bug not yet fixed. When a test passes despite being expected to fail (marked with pytest.mark.xfail), it’s an xpass and will be reported in the test summary.`